# How to fetch comment in realtime after submission - ReactJS

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have a post with some comments and a form to add comments. I want to display the added comment immediately after sending it to the Database using API without refreshing the page in real time. How can I do this?

Below is my code

```
const PostWidget = ({ post }) => {
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
    const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
    const [commentInput, setComment] = useState({
        commentcontent: '',
    });

    const [errorlist, setError] = useState([]);

    const handleInput = (e) => {
        e.persist();
        setComment({ ...commentInput, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
    }


    const submitComment = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        setLoading(true);

        const data = {
            post_id: post.postid,
            commentcontent: commentInput.commentcontent,
        };

        axios.post(`/api/store-comment`, data).then((res) => {
            if (res.data.status === 200) {
                toast.success(res.data.message, "success");
                setComment({
                    ...commentInput,
                    commentcontent: '',
                });
                setLoading(false);
            }
            else if (res.data.status === 422) {
                toast.error("There are errors with your comment", "", "error");
                setError(res.data.errors);
                setLoading(false);
            }
        });

    }
}
```

The form to send data. It sends to an api without refreshing page

```
<div className="form-group boxed">
    <div className="input-wrapper">
        <form onSubmit={submitComment}>
            <textarea type="text" name="commentcontent" className="comment-textarea" onChange={handleInput}
                value={commentInput.commentcontent} placeholder="Write your Comment" />
            <button type="submit" className="send-input">
                {loading ? <><span className="spinner-border spinner-border-sm spinner-comment" role="status"
                        aria-hidden="true"></span></> : <><i className="fi fi-rr-arrow-circle-right"></i></>}

            </button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Displaying Comments

```
{post.comment.map((comment) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <div class="item" key={post.postid}>
                <div class="avatar">
                    <img src="assets/img/sample/avatar/avatar1.jpg" alt="avatar" class="imaged w32 rounded" />
                </div>
                <div class="in">
                    <div class="singlecomment-header">
                        <h4 class="title">Diego Morata</h4>
                        <span class="time">just now</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="text">
                        {comment.commentcontent}
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    )
})}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use websockets for realtime commuincation, as soon as database gets a record emit a socket event from the server that contains recent comment data and then capture it at the frontend to update the UI.

Answer (score 0):

Use WebSockets to create a persistent connection with your server.

- When your post receives a comment, the server will emit an event through WebSocket.
- Since you're using react, you can put your socket listeners in useEffect which will update the UI when it receives new data.
- If you use any state management solution, the socket listeners in useEffect will help you update your state easily.

I would recommend using [socket.io](https://socket.io/) over native WS implementation, as it is easier to read and understand.